# xlwings hide worksheets from python and book not visible

Tags: python, xlwings

I'm using xlwings to control a workbook because I need to keep existing charts in tact (otherwise I'd use openpyxl). Is there a way to make the sheets hidden and to open a book within an app that is not visible?

to hide a sheet I've tried:

```
 wb.sheets[ws].Visible = False
 wb.sheets[ws].hidden= True
 wb.sheets[ws].Visible= xlveryhidden #vba syntax - bombs
```

The top two run, but don't do anything, the third bombs out.

I can create a new excel app and I can create a new book (which creates is new app). However, I want to open a specific book, but Book doesn't take a visible parameter - how do I open an existing workbook and not have it be visible?

```
excel  = xw.App(visible = False) #creates a new app that is visible
wb= xw.Book(filepath) #opens the already existing workbook, but it is visible - how do I make it part of the app above?
```

Answer (score 5):

The solution was to call .api before calling a VBA function:

```
wb.sheets[ws].api.Visible = False
```